# What is the difference between running a command in ssh shell manually vs running 'ssh user@host <command>?

Tags: ssh, bash

I was assuming it's the same, but it's not.

In my particular case a build script is working fine when executed as ./build.sh from ssh session on the build server like this

```
$ssh user@host
$./build.sh
```

but fails when ran as an ssh argument like this:

```
$ssh user@host /home/user/build.sh
```

or like this

```
$ssh user@host ./build.sh
```

The script itself just calls a bunch of binaries and their error messages are not very helpful for debugging.

But it shouldn't matter what is in the script, as long as the environment is the same, right? So what may be the difference?

Edit:
Don't know if it matters, but the described behavior happens on an ArchLinux Virtualbox guest without a desktop environment. I also tried the same on a Ubuntu18.04 VM with a desktop environment and the script worked correctly in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

The difference between the two cases is interactive vs non-interactive shell, which are indeed significantly different environments.

Instead of running the script as `$ssh user@host ./build.sh`, what worked was opening a login shell first by calling `bash -l`, like this:

```
$ssh user@host bash -l ./build.sh
```

I don't know if it makes the execution environment exactly the same as running the script manually via ssh, but it fixed the error in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a program to run, then ssh will start an interactive shell, for which a pseudo-terminal gets allocated.

If you specify a command to run, no pseudo-terminal allocation will take place, which will make some commands to fail (most notably the ones using the TERM variable, e.g. curses front-ends).

You can force terminal allocation using the `-t` switch, check if that solves your problem.

Comment: Just tried the `-t` switch. Unfortunately, the only difference it made was that the error output has become red.

Comment: On mobile now so I can’t test but I think that without the interactive shell you may also get a (much) more limited environment and scripts that rely on a complete environment with a full $PATH $JAVAHOME etc will b0rk. And you will need to set such required environment settings in the build.sh script

Comment: Is there a way to re-create this environment in the script?

Comment: @astreltsov Well, now that the text is red, it would be easier to find and ask a question about the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is this:

**ssh remote_host**
assumes that your username on your local machine is the same as that on the remote one, while if your username is different on the remoter machine, you need to parse the remote user's name in the format: **ssh username@remote-host**

There is no reason something like `ssh user@IP ./exe.sh` not to work if the script itself, permissions and path are good.

Comment: I'm specifying the username in both cases. And i'm using the same user in both cases. And the script does start in both cases, so the ssh connection is working properly, but one of the binaries called in yhe script behaves differently when the script called by ssh as opposed to calling it manually in the terminal

Comment: What is the exact error message ?